# What does a string literal mean in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

The [Coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) contain the following blurb

> String Interpolation, Block Strings, and Block Comments
>   Ruby-style string interpolation is included in CoffeeScript. Double-quoted strings allow for interpolated values, using #{ ... }, and single-quoted strings are literal.

Can someone explain what *"single-quoted strings are literal"* means here?

Does it just mean that there will be no interpretation?  Is there a more *javascripty* meaning?

I ask because I was seeing a difference when using a single quoted string vs a double quoted as a object key.

Comment: Does the phrase *"single-quoted strings are literals"* make it clearer?  I must confess I too was confused when I read that in their documentation the first time, but I think it's just a simple "tense confusion" error.

Comment: Ok, this may just be my lack of knowledge of javascript. I was unaware that String Literals were a _thing_. just read up on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals). Clears things up a bit.

Comment: Note that there is no actual semantic difference between a string delimited `'with single quotes'` or `"with double quotes"`. Both are treated exactly the same by the language. Which you use is just a matter of picking a convention and sticking to it. (Obviously I recommend my own that I mentioned below)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: You mean besides the semantic difference that you describe in your answer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that difference is in coffeescript - for javascript (which does not support interpolation) there is no difference at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name = "George"

"My Name: #{name}"    ====> "My Name: George"
'My Name: #{name}'    ====> "My Name: #{name}"
```

Literal in this case means that it is *literally* what you wrote in the string

For this reason (and a few others) I like to use a convention of double quotes when the string is natural language that is meaningful to an end user (for example an error message). And single quotes for symbols that are meaningful to the program (like property names, flags, module names, etc).

And no, that's not your fault, the word 'literal' has like 20 definitions in cs.

Comment: Ok, so I should be able to use both as a string key in Coffeescript?

Comment: And yeah, trying to determine what the word 'literal' means in coffeescript is confusing to newbies.

Comment: Yes, no difference whatsoever between them in javascript. In coffeescript, the only difference is that double quotes allow  interpolation and single do not.